# Logging in with username instead of email?

Tags: discussion, support

Can I log into Stack Overflow with my username (I've got a Stack Exchange account, of course) instead of having to enter my email?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Usernames are not unique, so there would be no way for Stack Overflow to know for certain what account to log you into.
As an extreme example, there are about [thirty pages of users named John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all&search=john+smith), give or take a few similar results in that search.